# Indent table pasted from Excel into Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am wondering how to indent pasted from Excel table in MS Word. What is possibly wrong in my current code as I am getting an error?

I have tried to use `rngPara.Indent`. My current code runs through Excel range and picks up "Cases" and builds up Word document according to each Case. Current Case pastes table5 `Case "table5"`

Part from my current code for copy - pasting Excel table:

```
   Dim wdRngPL As Object 'Word.Range
   Set wdRngPL = .Range.Characters.Last
    Case "table5"
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pricelist").Range("B31:D681").Copy
        With wdRngPL
        Set rngPara = .Paragraphs.Last.Range
        rngPara.Style = "Attachment"
        rngPara.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        '.Tables(.Tables.Count).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
        .Font.Hidden = 0
        rngPara.Indent
        Set rngPara = Nothing
        End With
```

I want to simulate manual work. If I remove `rngPara.Indent` then my process goes like this. Table is getting pasted to Word from Excel. I have to go to Word document select my table and hit **Increase Indent** one time.

Comment: What do you want to indent - the table itself or the cell contents? And by how much do you want to indent it?

Comment: @macropod I want to indent table by 2,3 cm from the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the table is being pasted at the end of a `Range` it's possible to pick up the `Table` object directly:

```
Dim tbl as Word.Table 'or Object
Set tbl = wdRngPL.Tables(wdRngPl.Tables.Count)
```

From that point, get the table's range and apply the desired formatting:

```
tbl.Range.Paragraphs.Indent
```

The reason the code in the question isn't giving the expected result is because `rngPara` probably doesn't contain the pasted content. To see this kind of thing, insert a `Select` method (rngPara.Select) for example, set a break point on the line after it, then look in the Word document at what's been selected. That will provide a clue about what's needed in order to address the required object.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am getting an error User defined type not defined and debugger is pointing to `Dim tbl As Word.Table 'or Object`

Comment: I have a lot of "cases" and actually after code has finished all tables in Word document have to indented. Maybe it is better to indent all the tables?

Comment: @user7202022 That `'or Object` is there in case you're using late-binding. Try dimming as Object rather than Word.Table. To the second comment: possibly - you need to decide that... Test it and see what works better, now that you have the code for indenting a table.

Comment: Solution that worked for each case is `.Tables(.Tables.Count).Range.Paragraphs.Indent` after `'.Tables(.Tables.Count).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow` in my code. However would be interesting to know how to indent all tables